# Entering the US with advance parole when having job and residence abroad or using ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

This weekend I have a flight to the US to attend a wedding. I would like to  know what is the best way to enter the US without getting stuck at the airport or getting troubles to reenter the US in the future.

I am on advance parole, meaning that I waiting for an adjustment of status and the green card. I took a job in Norway and moved there two months ago. My intentions are to work and live in Norway, not in the US. I do not have a job or an address in the US anymore. For this reason I do not care so much about getting a green card anymore, so I would not mind too much is my green card application gets denied.

My questions are:

1) When I arrive at immigration, should I try to use my advance parole? If the officer asks about my address in the US (which I do not have anymore) I will have to say that I am living in Norway?

2) Should I forget about the advance parole and enter with a ESTA? Other than possibly losing the green card (which is not a huge problem for me), could I get in trouble (getting stuck at the airport, possibly getting denied to access the US in the future)?

Update: see my answer below

Comment: [Alessandro](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/85627/alessandro)
Could you please give us an update on what happened to your greencard application?

Comment: @JoseLuis Good timing, I got my (useless for me) green card a couple of days ago. See my update below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I were in your shoes I'd apply for ESTA and use the visa waiver program.  The pending AOS application would be no basis to deny entry.  On the other hand, if your try to use the advance parole when you no longer intend to reside in the US you run the risk that the immigration officer might find that you are trying to gain entry through deception, and that can indeed result in a (lifetime) ban.

Comment: I just edited my second point (I meant ESTA, not VISTA). What you write confirms what I was thinking, i.e. to go for an ESTA. Thank you!

Comment: What do you think would happen if the officer asks me about my address and job and I answered the truth, that is that I live and work abroad?

Comment: @Alessandro You can give up your adjustment of status application at the border. You don't need to apply for a visa.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus it strikes me rather that the decision to abandon a pending AOS application and not to use a valid advance parole document is very strong evidence of an absence of immigrant intent.  Any reasonable person in these circumstances who still had immigrant intent would declare it at the border and use the advance parole.  Anyway there isn't sufficient time to get a visa.

Comment: @phoog "strong evidence of an absence of immigrant intent" yes, that is right. It would be out of scope to narrate why I had to apply for a green card when I was living there and what made me take this opportunity in Norway. In any case I live outside the US, I do not have an address in the US, but I would like to go for a few days to a wedding in the US. 
I already have an ESTA btw

Comment: @MichaelHampton It sounds to me that in case I abandoned my adjustment of status at the border (which is fine for me), I would need a VISA to enter in the US. Don't you agree? In any case I already applied for an ESTA. 
I will certainly update this post after the weekend

Comment: @Alessandro You won't need a visa, because you are a national of a country which is in the VWP.

Comment: I am a EU citizen and have no residency in Norway yet. That is why I needed a visa. I updated my post. Thank you all

Comment: @Alessandro but your update says that you entered the US without a visa.  With the Q and A format of this site, it is encouraged to answer your own question by [posting a separate answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) rather than by editing the question.

Comment: @phoog Ok I was confused, ESTA is not a visa. I entered with an ESTA. I followed your suggestion to write a separate answer

Comment: @Alessandro well it is indeed confusing, since some countries have something similar to ESTA that they call an e-visa, but the US defines its terms differently. Presumably this is at least in part because requiring travelers to have an e-visa to qualify for a "visa waiver" is logically problematic, to say the least.

Answer (score 5):

Update:
Everything went fine using an ESTA (point 2 in my question). The officer at the border noticed I have an expired J1 visa in my EU passport and just commented that I could renounce my green card and so on. I will see what happens with my Green Card and update this post.

Update 24 May 2019:
A couple of days ago my green card arrived. An American friend was kind enough to let us use their address, so it arrived there with 7/8 months of delay.

I do not really care about having a green card because I live elsewhere, but it is also not straight forward to stop the green card application and I did not have any reason to stop it

Comment: "I do not really care about having a green card cause I live elsewhere" You should care, because once you got a green card, you are subject to US taxes on your worldwide income no matter where you live, unless and until you formally give up your green card by filing I-407.

Comment: True. However, when I filed the US taxes in 2020 I had 0$ to pay. This is because I do not work in the US and Norway has a tax treaty with the US, so that I pay Norwegian taxes. As a side note, I did receive on my American bank account the full COVID bonus for unemployed person. Kind of silly that the US government is not aware that I am working but in another country

Comment: @aless80: if you mean the 'Economic Impact' payment of $1200 plus $500 per dependent child, that has nothing to do with 'unemployed'; it was paid to every citizen or LPR not a dependent of someone else, whether employed, unemployed, or retired, that IRS could identify. They even used Social Security and Veteran's Administration records to pay retirees and disabled that don't file income tax returns. Separately there were _increases_ and _extensions_ to preexisting unemployment insurance, but you would have had to apply for that if eligible which you weren't.

Comment: Right, what I wrote is not correct. However, it was 1,200 up to a gross income of $75k/150k per person/couple (no children), so I think I my family would have gotten less money in the end. The checks they did sound slightly bugged to me but maybe I am wrong